# Cómo pasar variable desde javascript (ajax) hacia controlador en Java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, jsp

Necesito pasar una variable desde una llamada ajax hacia el controlador en java. A las variables las rescato desde el jsp con javascript, y esa variable deseo pasarla al controlador pero no logro hacerlo.

```js
$('.descargarReporte').on('click', function () {
    var fechaInicio = "";
    var fechaFin = "";
    var fechas = "";
    var tipoReporte = document.getElementById('idReporteria').value;
    var rangoFecha = document.getElementById('idRFencha').value;

    fechas = rangoFecha.split(' - ');
    fechaInicio = fechas[0];
    fechaFin = fechas[1];

    $.ajax({
        url: ctx + "/nombreMetodo/descargaReporte",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {tipoReporte: tipoReporte, fechaInicio: fechaInicio, fechaFin: fechaFin}.....
```

En este caso deseo recibir esas variables en el controlador de Java.

Comment: y no las logras pasar porque..... por que? un error? salen bien llegan mal? no salen? no llegan? que ves en la pestaña de red de tu navegador? como podemos ayudarte sin mas info al respecto? que espera tu controlador? como las espera?

Comment: @gbianchi la verdad al parecer era problema de NetBeans (no es novedad), su clean and build realmente es necesario, era tan simple como poner un String tipoReporte = request.getParameter("tipoReporte"); con el mismo nombre, antes me lo traía null, pero ahora si me trae el valor desde el ajax. Muchas gracias de todas maneras!!!

Comment: Que extraño, llevo más de 10 años usando NetBeans, la verdad no he tenido problemas similares a los que comentas

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans siempre tira problemas; creo que cada cierto tiempo hay que darle un clean and build.
La variable en el controlador me la traía null, la forma de rescatarlo es tan simple como un

```java
String tipoReporte = request.getParameter("tipoReporte");
```

Debe ser con el mismo nombre con el que se rescata en el Ajax, funcionando todo bien.